# Почему в конструкцию lock заходят 22 нити?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, lock

У меня есть код, который по сокету принимает от клиентов пакеты обрабатывает их и отсылает ответ.
Из основной нити (при подключении клиента) создается дочерняя (назову ее T1). Дочерняя нить создается 2 раза (2 клиента подключаются), то есть так же создается нить Т2.

```
clientListenThread = new Thread(RecieveClientPackage);
clientListenThread.Start();
```

Каждая из этих нитей создает еще дочернюю нить (Т1.1 и Т2.1)

```
public void RecieveClientPackage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] buf = new byte[clientSocket.SendBufferSize];
            int receivedBytes = clientSocket.Receive(buf); // Получаем от клиента сериализованный пакет
            if (receivedBytes != 0)
            {
                package = new Package(buf); // В конструкторе пакет десериализуется/
                Thread dataProcessingThread = new Thread(DataProcessing);
                dataProcessingThread.Start();

            }
        }
    }
```

Мне нужно, чтобы код в методе DataProcessing выполнялся каждым потоком отдельно, поэтому я заворачиваю его в lock

```
void DataProcessing()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Функцию захватил поток {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            new DataProcessor(this);
            Console.WriteLine("Поток {0} освободил функцию", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }            
    }
```

В консоль для проверки вывожу какой поток зашел и вышел из lock. Вижу следующие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните мне пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. Спасибо!

Comment: `locker` - what is it?

Comment: private object locker = new object();
Поле класса

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы используете разные объекты в `lock(...)`, а надо - один и тот же.

```
object static locker = new object();
       ^^^^^^
void DataProcessing() 
{
  ...
```

Comment: Классика, которую нужно знать.